# Set manual IPv4 on 18.04-2 server install

Tags: server, 18.04, system-installation

I just tried to install Ubuntu server 18.04-2 and wanted to set IPv4 manually. I entered all the required data as subnet, ip, gateway and so on. But after I saved it all my data disapeared and it jumped back again to keyboard selection.

I seems as installation process just dont saves the manual IP settings.

Does anyone have the same experience?

Comment: If you put in a Search Domain, this is a KNOWN BUG that is fixed for the next point release, just populate search domain post-install in the netplan yaml.  This is fixed for the 18.04.3 ISO but they never respun .2

Answer (score -1):

Yep, seems to be an issue with that live version of the server iso.

Try http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.2/release/ - using the standard text installer worked for me.

Comment: yes, avoid the live-server image. That worked for me too.

Answer (score -2):

Yes On Setup Disabled the Network

[Disabled IPv4][1/3]

[Disabled IPv4][2/3]

[Disabled IPv4][3/3]

Finish Setup and configure IP static

sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

[IP Static]

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource. Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens160:
            dhcp4: no
            addresses:
            - 192.168.XX.XXX/24
            gateway4: 192.168.XX.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.XX.XX
                - 192.168.XX.XX
                search
                -DOMAIN
            optional: true
    version: 2
```